# Do all file-like objects in the Python standard library have a `name` attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basic file objects have a `name` attribute i.e.

```
>>> open("/dev/null").name
'/dev/null'
```

Do **all** other file-like types (e.g. GzipFile) in the standard library have this attribute?

Comment: If the file doesnt exist it gives an `IOError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for example a StringIO is a file-like object without `name` attribute. Most objects that are associated to an actual file have it, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: One (not even particularly obscure) counterexample is enough -- thanks.